Getting error DB Error: no such table in wordpress plugin
I am using the CiviCRM plugin in WordPress project, I have updated the plugin to the latest version and replaced it with the old version. Now when I find any contact and edit it, I get the error below error.
Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
DB Error: no such table.
This error DB Error: no such table. is also getting in main page of CIVIcrm plugin sometimes.
Need help.

Welcome to SE!  What is in your civicrm logfile?  That's usually in wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ConfigAndLog   What version were you on? What did you upgrade to?  Did you run the upgrade process after updating the files?  https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/wordpress/
